# Bootstrap & LESS: clean "reference" import

Tags: less

I read [@import (reference)](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference) and tried to import bootstrap without adding css chunks.

I thought the exported css file would be empty if my LESS file had just one single line:

```
@import (reference) "bootstrap";
```

but `export.css` has some lines:

```
d.thumbnail > img, ...
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.btn-group-lg > .btn {...}
.btn-group-sm > .btn {...}
.btn-group-xs > .btn {...}
.container:before, ...
.modal-footer:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.container:after, ...
.modal-footer:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

So why? Are they here for a reason?

I'm using Less 1.7.0 and Bootstrap 3.1.1.

Comment: This is known issue. "Reference" implementation has problems with certain nesting/self-referencing patterns. You can achieve more clean result by importing the compiled bootstrap CSS and individual mixin components (if necessary), e.g.: `@import (less, reference) ".../bootstrap.css"; @import ".../mixins.less";` etc.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Is there a link to the import reference issue? I want to read more about it.

Comment: @xeepete For above example it's [#1851](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1851#issuecomment-36456754) (also see issues referencing it for specific examples). But there're [more](https://github.com/less/less.js/search?q=import+reference&state=open&type=Issues).

Comment: @seven-phases-max please add your comments as answer so it can be accepted

Comment: @seven-phases-max Any recent developments?

Comment: @SalmanPK See [changelog](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) (in short: no).

Answer (score 0):

This is because `:extend` inside files Bootstrap.
You can use this (v.3.x.x):

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/variables.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/mixins.less";

// Reset and dependencies
// @import "bootstrap/normalize.less";
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/print.less";
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/glyphicons.less";

// Core CSS
@import (reference) "bootstrap/scaffolding.less";
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/type.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/code.less";
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/grid.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/tables.less";
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/forms.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/buttons.less";

// Components
@import (reference) "bootstrap/component-animations.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/dropdowns.less";
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/button-groups.less";
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/input-groups.less";
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/navs.less";
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/navbar.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/breadcrumbs.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/pagination.less";
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/pager.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/labels.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/badges.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/jumbotron.less";
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/thumbnails.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/alerts.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/progress-bars.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/media.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/list-group.less";
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/panels.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/responsive-embed.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/wells.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/close.less";

// Components w/ JavaScript
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/modals.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/tooltip.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/popovers.less";
// @import (reference) "bootstrap/carousel.less";

// Utility classes
@import (reference) "bootstrap/utilities.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/responsive-utilities.less";
```

But this is ridiculous :(